# Audio to Waveform Images

Tags: windows, audio, image

I'm looking for some recommendations on Windows software or Photoshop plugins that can create waveforms from audio files and save them as high resolution or vector images. I have tried this:

https://graphicriver.net/item/waveform-artist-mp3-to-waveform-poster/20644757

It works ok, but there's not too much customization in the style of the waveform. I have googled my ass off and can't seem to find anything remotely similar to that one.

These are the type of waveforms I would like to create if at all possible
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you into programming? Then wavesurfer.js could be your friend: https://wavesurfer.xyz/examples/?soundcloud.js

Comment: @Marcel Thanks, I did have a look at that a few months ago, but ended up using [waveform-path](https://jerosoler.github.io/waveform-path/)